# Tools to get HTML/CSS easily from PSD?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, tools, css

I have the PSD designs for my website and now want to create the site using these designs. I am not very good with css though I know HTML, javascript well. Is there any tool, site, software that can help me create an html and a css by drag-drop of controls.

I tried understanding the use of Blueprint CSS framework but could not gather much out of it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

There isn't software to do this well, mainly because it's such an inexact science.  You can try your luck with the export to HTML function in PS, but that generally produces very bad code.

Blueprint and other CSS frameworks won't help you much if you are not that familar with CSS, it's really meant to lay down the basics for your layout, it won't help much if you aren't comfortable with working within CSS to begin with.  Good luck.

Comment: try to use firebug plugin for mozilla, it helps a lot. But you will need the basics skills of css.

Answer (score 2):

Fireworks is better than Photoshop for this kind of work. Fireworks has always been a web design tool, whereas Photoshop was originally a tool for print designers.

Fireworks will open a PSD file and provides tools for creating interactive slices and the corresponding HTML. However like Wil says it is an inexact science and you will get much better results if you take the time to write your code by hand.

Comment: I agree that Fireworks > PSD for this type of thing but, ultimately, it's always a crapshoot unless you're building the HTML/CSS/JS yourself.

Answer (score 2):

When I'm trying to replicate the look of a design for the Web, I use a [*tracing image*](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=455360&seqNum=10) in Dreamweaver.

A tracing image puts your original design in the background of the WYSIWYG window, and then you can duplicate the design using Dreamweaver's tools.